# Unable to find modules from pydbgr in emacs

Tags: python, debugging, emacs

I am trying to get a decent python environment using emacs. As part of this process i want to integrate pydbgr with emacs.
I have almost done it but with an issue. When i try to start a debugging session pydbgr does not found my modules when i try to import them.

If i change PYTHONPATH and then execute pydbgr from command line all works fine.

So my question is. IS there any way to change python environment so i can debug with pydbgr inside emacs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Emacs Lisp function setenv as in:

(setenv "PYTHONPATH" "c:/....")